# Are path traversals attacks possible with invalid directories between?

Tags: php, unix

Let's say I can control the variable `$path` and the full path is generated as follows:

```
$full_path = "./valid_dir/docs/" . trim($path) ;
readfile($full_path) ;
```

where **`docs`** a non existent dir in the path.

Is it still possible ,with some trick perhaps to ignore docs, to perform a path traversal  attack ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it still possible ,with some trick perhaps to ignore docs, to perform a path traversal attack ?

Yes, it's pretty simple, just use `../` and it will be normalized before the file is opened (on *nix systems anyway, I don't know for sure on Windows).

Something like this would work.

```
$path = '../test.txt';
$full_path = "./valid_dir/docs/" . trim($path);
readfile($full_path);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've found the issue. I tried to put the case as simplified as possible and omited an if with file_exists(). readfile() does normalize but file_exists() does not :s